# Can I just mark missed data as 'NA' in Linear Regression for Multiple Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to train a model for linear regression of Multiple Classifier in ML. But the data is quite sparse. For some feature of string, if I mark those missed data as 'NA', is it a good practice? For data used for training, I can just drop those record with missed data. But how about the final data to do prediction are still sparse? How can I use a model to predict sparse data?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, by making the value as NA you are supposed to make it an outlier, and having an outlier is not a bad practice.
Again if you drop the records you might end up with very few data in your training set and i think your question is not well formed here, could you please elaborate on what type of data are you trying to apply classification ?

Comment: Thanks for replying! My data is for some commodities. I can get their features such like description, class, price, etc. Part of features are sparse. And I want to predict their sales in the future, say which commodities may be sold for more than 'x' units in the next 'y' days. My biggest concern is about the target data. I want to predict all target data so that I don't want to filter any data just because they have part of features missed. That is why I want to mark sparse features using 'NA'.